# In a table a column datatype is varchar, retrieve only those values of the column which are number / numeric using linq to sql

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have a table with a column of datatype `varchar`. I need to retrieve only those values from the column which are pure numbers. For this I used the Linq query shown below, which only checks for lower case alphabets. It won't able to check for this `@-1234`. I am providing the details what exactly I want to do.

```
   | input |     | expected output |
   | @!qw1 |     |      12345      |
   | 12345 |     |      90345      |
   | ab567 |     
   | 90345 |             
   | 123-q |
```

Code:

```
 pricingdemoEntities price = new pricingdemoEntities();

 var money = (from demos in price.demotables
              where false == (demos.value.Contains("a") || demos.value.Contains("b") || demos.value.Contains("c") || demos.value.Contains("d") || demos.value.Contains("e") || demos.value.Contains("f") || demos.value.Contains("g") || demos.value.Contains("h") ||
                              demos.value.Contains("i") || demos.value.Contains("j") || demos.value.Contains("k") || demos.value.Contains("l") ||
                              demos.value.Contains("m") || demos.value.Contains("n") || demos.value.Contains("o") || demos.value.Contains("p") || 
                              demos.value.Contains("q") || demos.value.Contains("r") || demos.value.Contains("s") || demos.value.Contains("t") || 
                              demos.value.Contains("u") || demos.value.Contains("v") || demos.value.Contains("w") || demos.value.Contains("x") ||
                              demos.value.Contains("y") || demos.value.Contains("z")) 
              select demos.value).ToList();

foreach (var final in money)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**`SqlFunctions.IsNumeric`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.isnumeric%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method.

```
using System.Data.Entity.SqlServer;

var money = (from demos in price.demotables
    where SqlFunctions.IsNumeric(demos.value) == 1
    select demos.value).ToList();
```

Comment: @reckface, other interesting extensions can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions_methods%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `long.TryParse` to check for the numeric value

```
pricingdemoEntities price = new pricingdemoEntities();
long num;
var money= (from demos in price.demotables

        where long.TryParse(demos.value.ToString(),out num) 
        select demos.value).ToList();
foreach (var final in money)
```

Comment: `long.TryParse(demos.value.ToString(),out num)` will not work in linq.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below example, may be this will help you out.

```
string[] stringList = { "123", "xsd", "%Vhh", "123H", "5841" }; // just an array of strings

var a = stringList.Where(x => x.All(char.IsDigit)); // checking for digits and returning them
```

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: can you pass me the code, which you are trying.. as the above code i tried is working fine.

Comment: @HiteshMistry Your code is not linq to entities. Try the same with something similar to the OP's code.

Comment: that's just an example, you just get the data using linq to entities in list or array then use the second line of my code.

Answer (score 0):

These queries cannot be translated to SQL by Entity Framework, so one option is to materialise your results first. This isn't very efficient, but you can improve it by limiting what you bring back in your query. And then perform the numeric check on the results.

For example:

```
var acceptable = ".,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"; // list of acceptable values
var nums = acceptable.Split(',').Select(a=> a[0]); // get the chars
using(var price = new pricingdemoEntities())
{
  // You can limit this even further by adding a take or additional where clauses
  var query = price.demotables.Select(p => p.value).AsEnumerable();
  var money = query.Where(q=> q.value.All(c=> nums.Contains(c)).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try use this

```
price.demotables.Where(x=>SqlFunctions.IsNumeric(x.Data)==1).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying every single character that makes the value not a number, it's much easier to just specify that you only want the value if it's a number.

So in raw SQL that could look something like this:

```
SELECT val
FROM table
WHERE ISNUMERIC(val) = 1
```

In `Entity Framework` you can create a similar query by using the handy [SqlFunctions.IsNumeric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.isnumeric(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

In your case it would look something like this:

```
var money = (
    from demos in price.demotables
    where SqlFunctions.IsNumeric(demos.value) == 1
    select demos.value).ToList();
```